# UI similar to Google Image Search

Tags: html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

In a webapp I have a list of items, each with a little information. I want to show more information when clicking on each item. I can pop a window using [Bootstrap Modal](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals), but I'd rather do something similar to what Google Image Search looks like.

When clicking on the item, I want to add some space below the item and fill it with the details.

Is there a control that already implements it? I couldn't find one. I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/) doesn't solve your issue, it'll probably help.